# How to prioritize E-Mails over Cache-Warmup in Shopware 6?

Tags: symfony, message-queue, shopware

In our Shopware 6 deployment we execute the following code after the application has deployed:

```
bin/console cache:clear
bin/console scheduled-task:register
bin/console cache:warmup
bin/console http:cache:warm:up
bin/console database:migrate --all
```

The `cache:warmup` causes the database table `enqueue` to be filled with ~460 rows and the messenger (`bin/console messenger:consume default`) starts handling the respective tasks. The message queue is `messages`.

System mail like "order confirmation" are handled in the same table under the same queue name.

We don't want the cache warmup to block all e-mails for an hour after the deployment for obvious reasons. How can I move the cache warmup / e-mail delivery to different queues or prioritize the emails in another way?